# Pivoting 4 by 44 result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, cte, unpivot

I have a **SQL Server** query that gets the sales data for a **44** store market chain, it includes 4 values for each store **(Sales, COGS, GP and GP Margin)**, I declared a **CTE** and joined it **44 times** for each store to get the **4** values as columns for each store as shown below:

Query: [Query1](https://rextester.com/CSJA13831)

[image: Result 1]

but when I try to use `PIVOT` function with dynamic SQL it returns multiple nulls as shown below:

Query:[Query2](https://rextester.com/CBCA62070)
[image: Result 2]

table `##tbl1` includes the data set that I want to pivot:
[image: ##tbl1]

I used the following query: (the three dots represent the rest of the columns to be pivoted)

```
select * from ##tbl1 

pivot (sum(total_sales)     for s in ([50001 Sales],[50002 Sales],...)) as pv_tb 
pivot (sum(Margin)          for m in ([50001 margin],[50002 margin],...)) as pv_tb1
pivot (sum(total_profit)    for p in ([50001 profit],[50002 profit],...)) as pv_tb2
pivot (sum(total_cost)      for c in ([50001 cost],[50002 cost],...)) as pv_tb3
```

I also use dynamic SQL to pass the column names inside `PIVOT()` without having to write each one of them individually, but for the sake of troubleshooting I just showed you how the query would look like.

I can't get around using `CROSS APPLY` and `UNPIVOT` with this **132** column result, it's very hard to maintain.

Can anyone help me find an easier way than this?

Comment: why do you not group them, if all other rows are NULL

Comment: I tried grouping them but still the same

Comment: can you reducwe your exampole to a  minimum and make a dbfiddle out of it please

Comment: here's the normal one [link](https://rextester.com/CSJA13831)

Comment: and this is the pivot method [link](https://rextester.com/CBCA62070) @nbk

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the end result you need? Right now it looks like **Query1** and **Query2** return the only possible ways to show that result set without changing the columns so either one of those queries should be what you're looking for if you're not trying to transpose the column structure. Otherwise if you're trying to transpose the columns into data points in the rows then please provide an example of what that result set should look like, e.g. something like `StoreId, Sales, COGS, GP, GPMargin`? I'm betting you really want to use `UNPIVOT` to solve your problem then.

Comment: @J.D. this is what I really want [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjPDf.png)

Comment: @HossamAladdin Ah ok, so doesn't your Query1 accomplish that?...or is your question that you're looking for a simpler way to re-write Query1?

Comment: thanks guys for your help, and to conclude, this dataset, the current query is sufficient and very easy to maintain, I just wanted to utilize PIVOT, UNPIVOT as an exercise or practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my dynamic solution for this question.  I think the issue you are having  with the pivot statement is that all of the columns are present when you pivot, which gives you those erroneous NULL's.  Even if they aren't in the select list, the pivot operator groups by them (see how I do a sub-select in the pivot section).

As for performance, under the hood, the performance difference is negligible, PIVOT and UNPIVOT are syntactic sugar over seemingly ugly/complicated SQL.  I do prefer using them though as I think it keeps the code easier to read with less noise.

In any case, this solution gives the results desired and does it dynamically.  The only thing that I had to change was the datatypes.  The UNPIVOT operator requires all to be the same datatype, so I just forced them to be NUMERIC(38,6), you may have to add a conversion step/CTE to the mix.

One thing to note is that it doesn't do any filtering of the source table.  If you need to add filtering then you will need to update it in multiple places or the query will start giving you those results with the NULL values.  Best to dump the results you want into a temp table in that case.

Finally: This really is a job best suited for the display layer to do.  I'm not sure where the results are going, but SSRS and Excel both have excellent pivot operations built in and they will do a better job of dynamically handling this than you can do in SQL.  Nevertheless, my solution:

```
/** BUILD UP BASE TABLE
    -I made it a temp table, but you can do whatever.
    **/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales 

CREATE TABLE #Sales (
    [CSSTOR] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [TOTAL_PRICE] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [Margin] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [TOTAL_Profit] [numeric](38, 6) NULL,
    [Total_COST] [numeric](38, 6) NULL
) 


INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50036,    25131.250,  12.876400   ,3236.008   ,21895.2421)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50026,    87732.470,  13.901600   ,12196.269  ,75536.2006)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50006,    77530.620,  13.841900   ,10731.743  ,66798.8770)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50017,    40097.190,  11.662900   ,4676.506   ,35420.6844)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50047,    45848.710,  14.268400   ,6541.888   ,39306.8219)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50037,    17029.810,  13.829900   ,2355.212   ,14674.5980)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50027,    75493.600,  14.490900   ,10939.739  ,64553.8611)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50007,    27153.030,  11.803900   ,3205.127   ,23947.9030)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50048,    46728.060,  12.531400   ,5855.688   ,40872.3721)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50028,    30872.940,  13.028200   ,4022.209   ,26850.7310)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50008,    61974.180,  13.886100   ,8605.854   ,53368.3260)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50038,    17190.610,  12.486200   ,2146.463   ,15044.1469)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50039,    48018.250,  5.346900    ,2567.526   ,45450.7237)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50049,    35941.500,  11.092800   ,3986.927   ,31954.5728)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50029,    44106.940,  13.131800   ,5792.052   ,38314.8880)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50019,    39339.940,  14.160600   ,5570.799   ,33769.1408)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50040,    40693.330,  12.369900   ,5033.752   ,35659.5784)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50030,    53085.970,  12.046700   ,6395.124   ,46690.8460)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50020,    61528.750,  13.056700   ,8033.643   ,53495.1072)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50010,    40194.330,  12.991800   ,5222.006   ,34972.3242)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50041,    40097.640,  12.226900   ,4902.718   ,35194.9217)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50031,    77884.530,  9.238900    ,7195.694   ,70688.8360)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50021,    90946.760,  12.355500   ,11236.982  ,79709.7779)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50001,    39498.300,  12.562300   ,4961.932   ,34536.3675)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50042,    64223.200,  13.290500   ,8535.633   ,55687.5668)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50032,    39490.130,  14.726000   ,5815.355   ,33674.7753)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50022,    66602.810,  12.567800   ,8370.569   ,58232.2408)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50012,    31329.510,  14.151300   ,4433.557   ,26895.9526)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50002,    31647.150,  11.159300   ,3531.624   ,28115.5264)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50043,    55461.870,  13.161100   ,7299.393   ,48162.4773)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50033,    35486.720,  8.224400    ,2918.604   ,32568.1158)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50023,    70549.250,  12.387900   ,8739.596   ,61809.6541)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50013,    35080.480,  13.330000   ,4676.263   ,30404.2168)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50003,    39691.180,  11.286800   ,4479.868   ,35211.3115)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50044,    33908.310,  11.479500   ,3892.531   ,30015.7794)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50034,    17208.780,  8.398300    ,1445.262   ,15763.5180)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50024,    37125.040,  10.122100   ,3757.867   ,33367.1726)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50014,    51475.620,  12.559800   ,6465.278   ,45010.3422)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50004,    67062.810,  13.691500   ,9181.943   ,57880.8672)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50045,    38778.360,  11.264400   ,4368.184   ,34410.1756)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50035,    19578.640,  10.538400   ,2063.281   ,17515.3589)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50025,    58158.960,  13.853000   ,8056.790   ,50102.1700)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50015,    34844.170,  8.108700    ,2825.443   ,32018.7270)
INSERT INTO #Sales VALUES(50005,    32089.110,  13.341200   ,4281.103   ,27808.0067)

DECLARE @SQLCMD NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CHeaderList NVARCHAR(MAX)

/** Build a list of headers in the correct order that we want (store order, then sales, margin, profit and cost).
    **/
SET @CHeaderList = (SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONCAT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), CSSTOR), ' - ', [Type]))), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), CSSTOR), [Sort])
                    FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT CSSTOR, [Type], [Sort]
                            FROM #Sales 
                                CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Sales', 1)
                                                    , ('Margin', 2)
                                                    , ('Profit', 3)
                                                    , ('Cost', 4)
                                                    ) AS P ([Type], [Sort])
                                                    ) AS D
                                                    )
/** Build up our dynamic sql command.
    CTE_Unpvt - Unpivots the data to a store/type/value array. 
        It also builds up a "CHeader" column that matches the pattern in the CHeaderList.  This gives us '50047 - Cost'
        for example.
    
    CTE_PVT - Pivots the data back to what we want using the CHeaderList above.  
    
    **/

SET @SQLCMD = N'
;WITH CTE_Unpvt AS
    (
    SELECT CSSTOR
        , [Type]
        , [Value]
        , CHeader = CONCAT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CSSTOR), '' - '', CASE WHEN [Type] = ''TOTAL_PRICE'' THEN ''Sales''
                                                                        WHEN [Type] = ''Margin'' THEN ''Margin''
                                                                        WHEN [Type] = ''TOTAL_Profit'' THEN ''Profit''
                                                                        WHEN [Type] = ''TOTAL_COST'' THEN ''Cost''
                                                                        ELSE '''' 
                                                                        END)
    FROM #Sales AS S
        UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR [Type] IN ([TOTAL_PRICE], [Margin], [TOTAL_Profit], [Total_COST])) AS Unpvt 
    )
, CTE_PVT AS
    (
    SELECT ' + @CHeaderList + '
    FROM (SELECT [Value], CHeader FROM CTE_Unpvt AS p) AS up
        PIVOT (SUM([Value]) FOR CHeader IN (' + @CHeaderList + ')) AS pvt
    )
SELECT * 
    , [TOTAL_SALES] = (SELECT SUM([TOTAL_PRICE]) FROM #Sales)
    , [TOTAL_MARGIN] = (SELECT SUM([Margin]) FROM #Sales)
    , [TOTAL_PROFIT] = (SELECT SUM([TOTAL_Profit]) FROM #Sales)
    , [TOTAL_COST] = (SELECT SUM([TOTAL_COST]) FROM #Sales)
FROM CTE_PVT'
    
EXEC (@SQLCMD)
```

Comment: Thanks @JonathanFite, that is a good answer, I think I'm going to try to implement it in a proc and share the results with you

Answer (score 1):

```
  WITH Sales_CTE ([50001 Sales], [50002 Sales], [50001 margin],[50002 margin],[50001 profit],[50002 profit],[50001 cost],[50002 cost])  
AS  
(    
select * from 
    (
    select rtrim(cast(csstor as char))+' Sales' as s
            ,rtrim(cast(csstor as char))+' margin' as m
            ,rtrim(cast(csstor as char))+' profit' as p
            ,rtrim(cast(csstor as char))+' cost' as c
            ,[TOTAL_PRICE]
            ,[Margin] 
            ,[TOTAL_Profit]     
            ,[Total_COST]
    from sales
    
    ) as result_1
pivot (sum(total_price)     for s in ([50001 Sales],[50002 Sales])) as pv_tb 
pivot (sum(Margin)          for m in ([50001 margin],[50002 margin])) as pv_tb1
pivot (sum(total_profit)    for p in ([50001 profit],[50002 profit])) as pv_tb2
pivot (sum(total_cost)      for c in ([50001 cost],[50002 cost])) as pv_tb3)
SELECT
MAX([50001 Sales]) as [50001 Sales]
, MAX([50002 Sales]) AS [50002 Sales]
, MAX([50001 margin]) AS [50001 margin]
,MAX([50002 margin]) AS [50002 margin]
,MAX([50001 profit]) AS [50002 margin]
,MAX([50002 profit]) AS [50002 profit]
,MAX([50001 cost]) AS [50001 cost]
,MAX([50002 cost]) AS [50002 cost]
FROM Sales_CTE
```

Result is

| 50001 Sales | 50002 Sales | 50001 margin | 50002 margin | 50002 margin | 50002 profit | 50001 cost | 50002 cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39498,300 | 31647,150 | 12,562300 | 11,159300 | 4961,932 | 3531,624 | 34536,3675 | 28115,5264 |

Comment: this is very good actually, but just remember, I need this for 44 stores, so it'll be 132 aliases and I already have the join method which is pretty neat.

Comment: you can create the aliases and the rest in a loop, but as you have already a dynamic sql, it is always some what difficult to program but it has nly be done once

Comment: sorry @nbk , I know it has been more than one year, could you have by any chance a tutorial for that loop that you were talking about?
thanks

Comment: @HossamAladdin you need dynamic sql  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/ and and a loop https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-while-loop-with-simple-examples/  but your version uis quite out of date

Comment: I'm currently using SQL Server 2019, and I created an sp that generates a dynamic pivot table for any table, but I still not able to achieve the solution above dynamically

Comment: you can insert the resultsets in a temporary table, but you sould ask a new qiuestion, te information you give very little information, your stored procedure must be already dynamic, so you should be able to add more variables to the mix and use them to identify all stores.

Comment: thank you @nbk for caring about this, you have given me a lot of insights, I actually got busy with other areas of SQL that I gave this one the least importance, but this challenge will not go unsolved, I'll take some time and try to solve it, and surely you'll be the first to know